# No result from a query stored in a VARCHAR2 variable is treated as an empty string or a NULL? - Oracle PL/SQL - Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, ora-06512, ora-06502

I have a procedure which performs a SELECT INTO and stores the returned result in a VARCHAR2 variable called `account_`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(XYZ_API.Get_Ref(company, currency, pay_type, order_id), 
                    XYZ_API.Get_Id(company, currency, pay_type, order_id)) account
INTO account_
FROM some_table
WHERE company                     = company_
     AND payment_type             = 'SUPP'
     AND order_id                 = order_id_
     AND payment_date             = pay_date_;
```

`company_`, `order_id_`, and `pay_date_` are all VARCHAR2 variables I am using to filter out the records.

The result taken into `account_` is then formatted as follows and stored in another VARCHAR2 variable named `giro_`:

`giro_ := LPAD( TRANSLATE( account_, '1234567890- ','1234567890' ), 16, '0' );`

Then I check whether `giro_` is a number, as follows with a FOR loop.

```
FOR i_ IN 1..LENGTH( giro_ ) LOOP
     c_ := ASCII( SUBSTR( giro_ , i_, 1 ) );
     IF ( c_ < ASCII( '0' ) OR c_ > ASCII( '9' ) ) THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;
```

I have a scenario where the SELECT query shown above does not pick up any records.

This eventually introduces an exception in the FOR loop with errors ORA-06502 and ORA-06512.

As per my understanding the cause is `LENGTH( giro_ )`.

`1..LENGTH( giro_ )` is failing as the LENGTH of `giro_` value (LENGTH being a NULL) cannot be converted into a NUMBER.

My question is, by this time in this scenario, is `giro_` an empty string or a NULL?
What exactly happens here?

Thanks!

Comment: While I've come to appreciate that the empty string and NULL are the same in Oracle, `LENGTH` is one of very few drawbacks. It returns NULL rather than zero in case of an empty string.  It is strange by the way that you see the necessity of using `DISTINCT`, but see it guaranteed to get thus exactly one result row. This may indicate a poor data model or a not so robust query.

Comment: Yes I agree to what you are saying. I will try to make amends to my data/query :)
thank you for the input!

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is wrong. `LENGTH` will always return a number (string length), it doesn't check whether its argument *is* a number.

Exception from the rule is if its (`LENGTH`'s) argument is an empty string (in Oracle, it is equal to `NULL`) - then the length is also *unknown* (`NULL`):

```
SQL> select length(''), length(null) from dual;

LENGTH('') LENGTH(NULL)
---------- ------------


SQL>
```

In that case, modify your code so that it includes the `NVL` function, e.g.

```
FOR i_ IN 1 .. NVL(LENGTH( giro_ ), 0) LOOP
```

For empty strings, it won't do anything.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. I think you are agreeing to my point in the question?
when I said, "1..LENGTH( giro_ ) is failing as the LENGTH of giro_ value cannot be converted into a NUMBER" I meant that the code is failing because the return value from LENGTH is a NULL here. So, the loop can't go from 1 to NULL, it should be 1 to some number.

Comment: You're welcome. Exactly :) Sorry if I misunderstood what you were saying.